# Escaping SQL queries in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I am inserting some data into a MySQL table using CodeIgniter. Because I am using `INSERT IGNORE INTO` and do not want to edit the active records class to enable this feature, I am generating the SQL query manually.

```
$this->db->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO my_table(lat, lng, date, type)
                        VALUES ('" . $data['lat'] . "', '" . $data['lng'] . "', '" . $data['date'] . "', '" . $data['type'] . "')");
```

**Problem:** The query failed when the string in `$data['type']` contained a single quote. How can I make it such that these characters that need to be escaped gets escaped automatically, like when using Active records?

Comment: And what about in a SELECT query? How I can escape them?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Another way is to use Query Binding which automatically escapes all the values:

```
$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO my_table(lat, lng, date, type) VALUES (?,?,?,?);"; 
$this->db->query($sql, array($data['lat'], $data['lng'], $data['date'], $data['type']));
```

Comment: You can make this even simpler:
`$this->db->query($sql, $data);`
This works for me! (I guess you shouldn't have any other keys in the data array for it to work)

Comment: Or rewrite it to Active Record Pattern: `$this->db->inset('some_table', $data);` much more straight forward and very easy. Just make sure that no auto-increment primary key field makes it into `insert()` method by using `if (!isset($data['id'])) throw new { InvalidArgumentException('data[id] is not allowed for insert'); }`

Answer (score 11):

use **$this->db->escape();** it will escape the string automatically

> This function determines the data type so that it can escape only
>   string data. It also automatically adds single quotes around the data
>   so you don't have to:

```
$this->db->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO my_table(lat, lng, date, type)
VALUES ('" . $this->db->escape($data['lat']) . "', '" . $this->db->escape($data['lng']) . "', '" . $this->db->escape($data['date']$this->db->escape . "', '" . $this->db->escape($data['type']) . "')");
```

Here is the reference [Click Here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html)

Comment: At the very end of the page, the section about parameter binding is a *much* better option ;)

Comment: updated link: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/queries.html

Comment: $this->db->escape() adds the single quotes so we don't have to, yet in your query you have added them.(I don't know if its the version difference or what, I am using 3.1.*) Earlier today I was writing a query and then I faced a Problem where I had made this mistake.