# removing quotes created by $this->db->escape without messing out original text

Tags: php, codeigniter, quotes

I'm using `$this->db->escape` in before inserting data in my db, however, when I query the db for that data, I'm having problems getting rid of the quotes.

I'm using `str_replace("'", "",$p->post_text);` but it removes all the single quotes as expected. If  `$p->post_text` is a string like "I'm not gonna work for mary's brother no more"
it will remove those as well. I noticed that the a backslash is added to single quotes that are on the the string and not on the ones generated by php.

So I tried :

```
 $post_text = str_replace("'", "",$p->post_text);
 $post_text1 = stripslashes($post_text);
```

Still not working. I guess the slashes are stripped automatically.

Any help will be appreciated.

UPDATED ADDED INSERT QUERY:

```
 $data = array('aluno_id' => $myid,
               'post_text' => $this->db->escape($text),
               'post_image' => $this->db->escape($img),
               'youtube_link' => $this->db->escape($video_code),
               'media_top' => $this->db->escape($media_top),
               'post_date' => date(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) 

                            );

 $this->db->insert('mutamba_posts',$data);
```

Comment: how is your insert command ?

Comment: Wait, does CI make you escape stuff when you pass it like that?  That seems messed up.  I'd think it would do the escaping for you.

Comment: @cHao I usually just do `'post_text' => $text` but I read on [elislab](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html) that it's safer to escape it using `$this->db->escape`.

Comment: `query` and `insert` are two different things.  `insert` apparently escapes for you.  And you want the data escaped exactly once -- 0 times is unsafe, but 2 or more times gives you junked up data.

Comment: @cHao  not sure I understand, you are saying I shouldn't use the `$this->db->escape` on inserting?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968527/escaping-sql-queries-in-codeigniter

Comment: Right.  `escape` is for when you're building queries by hand and such.  See https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert , particularly that red box at the end of the section.  They're escaping the data you pass to `insert`, so you shouldn't be escaping it yourself.

Comment: @cHao I knew it! this page https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html]https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html confused me a little thanks for your quick reply ;)

Answer (score 4):

Although its an old question but no solution so i add this.

Try using

```
$this->db->escape_str($YOUR_STRING);
```