# Storing content along with special characters in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have an `add_post` form which include `post_title`, `post_content` and `date`. `post_content` may contain special_characters and HTML elements

There is a problem to store into post_content

Example string:

> gyms revolve around this unique factor called “Community.”

If I try to insert that string into the database table the following string is inserted for instance:

> gyms revolve around this unique factor called

Because of the symbols (`“` `”` `’`)  I am not able to insert the all data

I just want to remove these symbols so that I would be able to add all `post_content` data

This is what I have tried:

```
 $post_content=$_POST['post_content']; 
 $post_content=addslashes($post_content);
 $post_content=htmlentities($post_content);
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/5828/pdo/2685/preventing-sql-injection-with-parameterized-queries#t=201703100659054502665

Comment: How are you inserting the data into your database? Which database are you using? Which charset in your database? Your question is not clear and does not show any research effort.

Comment: You've mentioned in several comments below that you have tried `mysql_real_escape_string` but it has not worked. Please explain **clearly** how and why this has not worked

Comment: `$this->db->insert('posts', $data);`

Comment: your question heading **Storing content along with special characters in PHP** contradicts to what you want to do _I just want to remove these symbols so that I would be able to add all post_content data_

Comment: @KeithAsilom I just want to remove some symbols that I mention in question, not all symbols.

Comment: so you only want to remove single and double quotes but retain all other special characters? what about when retrieving, do you want the single/double quote again?

Comment: @deep 3015's solution should have work for you

Comment: @KeithAsilom While retrieving I don't want those symbols again.

Answer (score 3):

*I just want to remove these symbols so that I would be able to add all post_content data.*

Answering to this (which is different from question heading i quess) you can actually remove special characters before saving in database in the controller it self using function

```
public function clean($string) {
   $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.
   $string = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.
   $string =preg_replace('/-/', ' ', $string); // Replace hyphens with spaces.
   $string =preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $string); //remove extra spaces
   return $string;
}

public function somFun(){
    $post_content=$_POST['post_content']; 
    $post_content=$this->clean(post_content);
    //proceed to modal function for saving in database
}
```

**Edit**
To remove single and double quotes only

```
public function somFun(){
    $post_content=$_POST['post_content']; 
    $post_content=str_replace(array("'", "\"","“","”","’"), "", $post_content );
    $post_content=preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $post_content); /*remove extra spaces*/
    //proceed to modal function for saving in database
}
```

You can do test using [on line code tester](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/)

```
<?php
$str = "'test 'this' “ ” ’ string'";
$str= str_replace(array("'", "\"","“","”","’"), "", $str );
$str=preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $str);
echo $str;
```

result will be `test this string`

Comment: Post content may include special symbols, so that I don't want to remove all special symbols I just want to remove or escape these (“ ” ’) symbols.

Answer (score 2):

If you using **CodeIgniter**, there is related questions about that, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968527/escaping-sql-queries-in-codeigniter) and [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/queries.html), you have two choices :

**Use query building :** Data will be escaped by PDO

```
$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO my_table(lat, lng, date, type) VALUES (?,?,?,?);"; 
$this->db->query($sql, array($data['lat'], $data['lng'], $data['date'], $data['type']));
```

**Use db->escape() method :** Explicitly escape data

```
$this->db->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO my_table(lat, lng, date, type) VALUES ('" . $this->db->escape($data['lat']) . "', '" .  $this->db->escape($data['lng']) . "', '" . $this->db->escape($data['date']$this->db->escape . "', '" . $this->db->escape($data['type']) . "')");
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 2):

utf8 problem.

`“ ” ’` are not ordinary ascii characters.  If they are mis-fed to a `CHARACTER SET utf8` column, the strings may be truncated.  Is that what is happening?  You get all the text up to, but not including, one of those quote charaters?  If so, then the explanation and tips on fixing *your code and/or schema* are [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) -- search for "truncate".

The probable problem is that the bytes fed in are encoded in latin1, not utf8, yet the connection is specified to be UTF-8 and the table/column is column is `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or utf8mb4).

Since those characters are not recognized by PHP or MySQL as quotes, many of the other suggestions have no effect.

Comment: @ Rick Yes I get all the text up to the symbols I mentioned in question. suppose I have a string - gyms revolve around this unique factor called “Community.”  It is within this Community. Something like this then the data stored will be like - gyms revolve around this unique factor called. When It get the symbols then string truncated from that point and stored to database.

Comment: Actually I have a mass upload form. Using csv file I can upload many records simultaneously. css file include those symbols.

Comment: @Deepak are you using `fgetcsv()` when reading your csv file? If this is utf8 problem, maybe you can try : `$data = fgetcsv("file.csv", "r");` `$data = array_map("utf8_encode", $data);`  - array_map sends each value of the $data to utf8_encode function. After encoding values to utf8 then maybe you can now try the suggestions like `str_replace` or `preg_replace`

Comment: @KeithAsilom Yes I am using fgetcsv(). Here is my code - $data=array();
          $file = fopen($filename, "r");
           while (($importdata = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
           {
      $data[sizeof($data)]=$importdata;
           }
   fclose($file);

Comment: can you try adding this as first line inside your while statement: `$importdata = array_map("utf8_encode", $importdata );`

Comment: @KeithAsilom Yes it is working. Thank you very much.

Comment: If _everything_ is set to utf8, you don't need `utf8_encode`.

Answer (score 1):

You could always just [base64_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) these values, then it doesn't matter what's in them.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove

```
<?php
$html="a“”’b";
$res = preg_replace('/[^\x20-\x7E]/','', $html);
echo $res;
?>
```

Output **ab**

Answer (score 1):

I have done same things with one trick

```
$html = base64_encode($this->input->post->('key'));
```

and at display time decode it !

it will solve all special characters problems

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysql_real_escape_string`

For Example

```
$name='abc,cf';
 $name=mysql_real_escape_string($name);
```

Answer (score 0):

try use form helper to insert data and try like this`set_value('description')`  or use this `htmlspecialchars($POST['description'])` i use this to save data into database, and use to showing like this `htmlspecialchars_decode($description)`

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know why you use mysqli_real_escape_string or why you need that to insert "" into the database, i use codeigniter to and insert text into my database with no problem, traid this

in the controller

```
 $coments = $this->input->post('comentario', true); 
    $query = $obj->Insertcoments($coments);
```

and in the model

```
function Insert($coments) {
        $data = array(
            'mensaje' => $coments);
        $this->db->insert('mensaje', $data);
    }
```