# how to apply timestampdiff in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

Good Day!

I am newbie into writing a program,

I need to get the timestampdiff between my 2 column with data type as datetime-local.

below is a sql query that suitable syntax to get the outage duration

```
SELECT timestampdiff(hour,DateStarted,DateRestored) as Outage from network_outage
```

however I have no idea how to insert this one in to my database
I am using codeigniter framework

see below model code

```
    function get_networkoutage($OutageDuration)
      {
        $this->db->select('timestampdiff(DateStarted,DateRestored) as OutageDuration',$OutageDuration);
          $query = $this->db->get('network_outage');
          return $query;
      }
```

below is my Controller code

```
    $data['NetworkOutage'] = $this->network_model->get_networkoutage($OutageDuration);
```

after echoing NetworkOutage in view page
it gives me an error

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: OutageDuration

Filename: controllers/Site.php

Line Number: 59

Backtrace:

File: D:\xampp\htdocs\itsystem\application\controllers\Site.php
Line: 59
Function: _error_handler

File: D:\xampp\htdocs\itsystem\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DateStarted, DateRestored) as OutageDuration FROM `network_outage`' at line 1

SELECT timestampdiff(DateStarted, DateRestored) as OutageDuration FROM `network_outage`

Filename: D:/xampp/htdocs/itsystem/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

Thank you and best regards,

Comment: so what have you tried? do you want a PHP or MySQL-based solution? in your previous attempts, what has gone wrong? what errors are you getting?

Comment: Hi Sir,
I never tried anything yet.
I am not that sure what is the best practices in doing this,

in my case, I want to automatically calculate the time difference when the DateRestored is have value on it

here is the procedure, when the problem occurs I am going to put date and time when it was started once it was resolve I will update the form and I wanted that it will be automatically calcucated the TimeDifference and inserted it into the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is a reference to [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10907750/calculate-difference-between-two-datetimes-in-mysql), because I can not add it as a comment.

SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '2012-06-06 13:13:55', '2012-06-06 15:20:18')
will return 7583.
As first argument you can use MICROSECOND (microseconds), SECOND, MINUTE, HOUR, DAY, WEEK, MONTH, QUARTER, or YEAR.
Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Sir,

Thank you for this idea,
this answer my problem.

I am using codeigniter,I cannot think how to insert automatically this  to the database using the codeigniter.

thanks in advance

Comment: Most (i'm not sure to every) frameworks provide to insert sql statement as string. If you have to use this solution you have to read about for $this->db->escape().
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html . And you can see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968527/escaping-sql-queries-in-codeigniter (query with escape example)

Comment: Hi Ivan,
 I am updating my questions the sql syntax you have provided seems fits my needs

however, I have no idea on how to implement this one in using codeigniter

I wanted to get the value atleast

thank you

Comment: Hi Arjay. First check what is the value of $OutageDuration. Second (just for info) for query debug you can see $this->db->last_query(). I think the problem is in $OutageDuration or in way that it is assigned.

Comment: Hi Sir Ivan,

I really appreciate your time on helping me resolvin this concerns of mine.

using the provided sql syntax I come up on creating views with timestampdiff syntax after having the temporay table I fetch them from database and it seems it now help me to resolve my problems.

Thank you very much,